# Does every element in a set have to pair with itself to be reflexive?

Tags: relation, discrete-mathematics

I have a relation where (0,0), but the other elements don't pair with themselves. Does only one element have to meet the reflexive condition for it to be reflexive?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A binary relation R on set S is reflexive if and only if for every element x in S we have x R x. A common trick question goes something like this:

> Prove or disprove: every symmetric, transitive relation is reflexive.

It turns out to be false since you can maintain symmetry and transitivity by not relating elements. However, to be reflexive requires you relate them (to themselves).